# Javascript add a percentage based on previous value result

Tags: javascript, percentage

I have a little function in javascript where i need to add percentages to a number,
But it needs to add that percentage to the previous result line everytime, i can't figure this out

```
(function () {

if(fieldname5 == 18 && fieldname6 == 1) return fieldname38;
if(fieldname5 == 18 && fieldname6 == 2) return fieldname38*(5.30/100);
if(fieldname5 == 18 && fieldname6 == 3) return fieldname38*(5.20/100);
if(fieldname5 == 18 && fieldname6 == 4) return fieldname38*(5.10/100);
if(fieldname5 == 18 && fieldname6 == 5) return fieldname38*(5.00/100);

})()
```

This is not working because it adds the percentage to the same value fieldname38 everytime
But i need to add the next percentage to the previous result.

So fieldname38 = 20000 + 5.30% = 210600
next line needs to add 5.20% to previous result (210600) = 221551.2

Could someone show me an example please ?

Comment: I don't understand your question. Can you maybe add some examples of input & expected output?

Comment: Indexed variable names are a big no-no. You've to get familiar with [Arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/array). What comes to the question itself, you've already answered it, "_fieldname38 = 20000 + 5.30% ..._", where you just replace the constant 20000 with `fieldname38`.

Comment: ex: fieldname1 returns a value 100, i add 5.30% to that value = 105.3 next line i need to add 5.20% to 105.3 = 110.77 next line i add 5.10% to 110.77 = 116.41 etc....

Answer (score 0):

This?

```js
const vals = [1,1,.0053,.0052,.0051,.005]
if(fieldname5 == 18)
  for (let i=1;i<=fieldname6;i++) {
    fieldname38 += fieldname38*vals[i]
  }
  return fieldname38;
}
```

Comment: Why are you aggregating? you should pick one option and `fieldname6` has no case with 0.

Comment: Because OP said to aggregate: `fieldname38 = 20000 + 5.30% = 210600 next line needs to add 5.20% to previous result (210600) = 221551.2`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
var taxLevel = [1,5.30,5.20,5.10,5.00];
if(taxLevel.length<fieldname6 && fieldname6<0 && fieldname5 == 18){
    return fieldname38*(taxLevel[fieldname6-1]/100)
}
```

Comment: Wow you guys are quick, thanks for this, i will try and let you know !

Answer (score 0):

This is the correct way in my case and working like a charm, inspired by @mplungjan

```
(function () {
var vals = [1,1,0.053,0.052,0.051,0.05], result = fieldname38;

if(fieldname5 == 18)
for (let i=1;i<=fieldname6;i++) result += result*vals[i];
return result;
})()
```

Enjoy !

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of returning on each line, you want to assign a value to fieldname38, like so:

```js
(function () {
    if (fieldname5 == 18 && fieldname6 == 2) {
        fieldname38 = fieldname38 * (5.30 / 100);
    }

    if (fieldname5 == 18 && fieldname6 == 3) {
        fieldname38 = fieldname38 * (5.20 / 100);
    }

    if (fieldname5 == 18 && fieldname6 == 4) {
        fieldname38 = fieldname38 * (5.10 / 100);
    }

    if (fieldname5 == 18 && fieldname6 == 5) {
        fieldname38 = fieldname38 * (5.00 / 100);
    }
    return fieldname38;
})();
```